# What does this JQuery code work for filtering data from a table?

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain to me what does this code below do ?

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('input.filter').on('keyup', function() {
          var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
          $('.searchable tr').hide();
          $('.searchable tr').filter(function() {
               return rex.test($(this).text());
          }).show();
      });
 });
</script>
```

it filters out the data in a table, depending on the input's value.

I can understand the basic functions but I am missing the overall thinking concept.

Can someone please explain ?

Comment: There should be a RegExp in that input.filter field, which is used, to test all entries in the table rows. All are hidden, and then those, that match the RegExp, are shown again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you type something(keyup event), hide all the `<tr>`, then look for all the `<tr>` that contains the text you typed, and then display them.

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

     // key up from an input with class filter
     $('input.filter').on('keyup', function() {

          // create regular expression from value of the input
          var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');

          // hide all <tr>
          $('.searchable tr').hide();

          // show all <tr> which contains your text
          $('.searchable tr').filter(function() {
               return rex.test($(this).text());
          }).show();
      }); 
}); 
</script>
```

**The regex part:**

> var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');

This will create a regex which will match the value you entered in the input. `i` argument means case insensitive.

In the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), you're testing `return rex.test($(this).text());`. Here, you're using a custom filter function. Only rows containing your text won't be filtered out (and then those rows are shown).

For example:

```
var rex = new RegExp('hello', 'i'); //you typed "hello" in the input
rex.test('hello world'); // true - contains hello
rex.test('HEllo world'); // true - contains hello (case insensitive)
rex.test('lorem ipsum'); // false - no hello present
```

**jQuery filter()**

If you have the following HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://google.com" rel="nofollow">Link 2</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com">Link 3</a>
<a href="http://bing.com" class="red">Link 4</a>
<a href="http://www.bing.com" class="red">Link 5</a>
<a href="http://localgoogle.com">Link 6</a>
```

and you run `$('a').hide().filter('.red').show();`, only `Link 4` and `Link 5` will be shown. It's the same concept for you, but with a custom filter instead.

Comment: that's the overall idea but I am looking into something more detailed than this

Comment: What do you want to know specifically?

Comment: mostly the regex parts and what do they have to do with the rest of the script.